# Tub Cartridge Identification

Tags: cartridge

Does anyone recognize this tub cartridge?
[image]

[image]

Comment: There's  thousand cartridges out there that look like this one.....  we'll need more than a picture.

Comment: More than a picture? No identification number stamped on the cartridge or valve body. Nothing on the inside of the cover plate. There are several options which is why I’m asking.

Comment: Take a picture of the faucet and the cartridge to a local True Value store, or a plumbing parts supplier, they will match it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a lot like this Peerless RP70538, but your stem is a little longer/different.  Based on this, I'm pretty confident its a Peerless cartridge.  Maybe the longer stem detaches?

[https://www.amazon.com/Single-Function-Pressure-Cartridge-Compatible-Peerless/dp/B08PQQ2XP1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08PQQ2XP1)

I guess it could also be a foreign copy of a Peerless/Delta faucet as well.